# What is the point of using -o - in curl?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, curl

I see a lot of bash install scripts that goes like this

```
curl -o- http://example.org/script.sh | bash
```

Eg: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script

As far as I know writing to stdout is the default behaviour of curl.
Is there a specific reason to use this in any case?

Comment: I've never seen this. Do you have a couple of examples?

Comment: @the other guy this is the one that made me ask this question today https://github.com/engineer-man/piston. Check the installation section. Although I'm pretty sure I've seen people use this before.

Comment: That's copied from `nvm` where it was added in [this commit](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/commit/f70530ef18316d7abadc23ae23b760e18f57a3d3) that just says "Fix installation instructions." :\

Comment: @Abe1242 You should [edit] your question and add the reference to the example there instead of using comments to add information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you note, `-o -` is the default behavior out of the box; but users might have a `.curlrc` file which specifies a different local default.

Also, `-o -` somewhat helps document to readers who are unfamiliar with `curl` what's going on.